# Changing Template10 Header Height

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, template10

I have a Template10 UWP application that I am developing, and for the most part everything is coming together nicely. However, I am a little stumped about the behavior of the `PageHeader` control when an `AppBarButton` has a `Label` set.

As you can see in the shot below, the header does not show the `Label` under the displayed `Icon`.

[image: default header]

But when I click on the `...` to expand the `SecondaryCommands`, the height adjusts to accomodate the `Label` and the dropdown menu is displayed properly. Is there a way to set this as the default behavior of the `PageHeader` and have the back arrow and title be vertically centered? It looks a little odd once the header expands and the title is still top aligned.

[image: expanded header]

**EDIT**

I would like to note, that simply changing the `VerticalAlignment` of the `PageHeader` does not change this behavior at all. The result still looks the same. I thought perhaps if I changed the alignment then I would just have to manually set the `Height`. Also, even manually setting the `Height` doesn't change anything either, the `Background` stays the same height and the text doesn't move either.

**EDIT 2**

Sorry for the poor scaling, but here is what it looks like animated, for the most part:

[image: animated gif]

I am hoping to vertically align the back arrow, Invoice Details, the `AppBarSeparator`, and the ellipses. The `AppBarSeparator` is easy, I just added `VerticalAlignment="Center"` and it adjusts. What I'm looking for is the expanded version of the header, with the mentioned items centered, that doesn't change height when clicking the ellipses.

I've looked through the source code for Template 10, and the closest thing I can find is the `IsOpen` property on `PageHeader` but if I set that to `True` then the header just looks like the second picture with the menu expanded. I am just looking for something to make the header look expanded, but without the menu (and stay expanded when menu appears, etc.)